# Pandas isin with empty dataframe produces epoch value on datetime type instead of boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I've noticed that doing an `isin` on a DataFrame which contains datetime types where the operand is an empty DataFrame produces epoch datetime values (i.e. 1970-01-01), instead of 'False'. It seems unlikely that this is correct?

The following code demonstrates this:

(pandas = 0.19.2, numpy = 1.12.0)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2014-05-01 18:47:05.069722', '2014-05-01 18:47:05.119994', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.178768']}
data2 = {'date': ['2014-05-01 18:47:05.069722', '2014-05-01 18:47:05.119994']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ['date'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame()

print df.isin(df2)
print df.isin(df3)
print df.isin(df4)
```

This outputs:

```
    date
0   True
1   True
2  False
    date
0 1970-01-01
1 1970-01-01
2 1970-01-01
    date
0 1970-01-01
1 1970-01-01
2 1970-01-01
```

I would normally expect a list of False values instead of '1970-01-01'? I notice that with pandas = 0.16.2 and numpy = 1.9.2,  `df.isin(df3)` produces the more expected:

```
   date
0  False
1  False
2  False
```

But `df.isin(df4)` is as previous.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. I would report it to the pandas developers at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely looks like a bug to me. [`isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) calls [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) as seen [in the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/frame.py#L5251-L5324), and the odd behavior is reproducible with `DataFrame.eq` itself.

```
>>> df
                        date
0 2014-05-01 18:47:05.069722
1 2014-05-01 18:47:05.119994
2 2014-05-02 18:47:05.178768

>>> df.eq(pd.DataFrame(dict(date=[np.nan]*3)))
        date
0 1970-01-01
1 1970-01-01
2 1970-01-01
```

---

I see you've now raised it to be an open issue,

- [Pandas `isin` with empty dataframe produces epoch value on datetime type instead of boolean #15473](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15473)

and it should be resolved for an upcoming release.